# Pandas split DataFrame by time delta and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Having the following DF:

```
   id          event_time
0   a 2020-10-21 01:00:34
1   a 2020-10-21 01:03:13
2   a 2020-10-21 01:05:13
3   a 2020-10-21 01:11:25
4   a 2020-10-21 01:12:25
5   a 2020-10-21 01:13:25
6   b 2020-10-21 01:21:25
7   b 2020-10-21 01:30:25
8   b 2020-10-21 01:31:25
9   b 2020-10-21 01:32:20
10  b 2020-10-21 01:33:25
11  b 2020-10-21 01:34:12
12  b 2020-10-21 01:40:00
13  b 2020-10-21 01:41:48
14  b 2020-10-21 01:42:15
```

I'm trying to split the DataFrame by `id` and a gap of `5min` delta. I've written the following code to mark the rows where split occurred:

```
df.event_time = pd.to_datetime(df.event_time)
df['delta'] = df.groupby('id').event_time.diff() > pd.to_timedelta('00:05:00')



   id          event_time  delta
0   a 2020-10-21 01:00:34  False
1   a 2020-10-21 01:03:13  False
2   a 2020-10-21 01:05:13  False
3   a 2020-10-21 01:11:25   True
4   a 2020-10-21 01:12:25  False
5   a 2020-10-21 01:13:25  False
6   b 2020-10-21 01:21:25  False
7   b 2020-10-21 01:30:25   True
8   b 2020-10-21 01:31:25  False
9   b 2020-10-21 01:32:20  False
10  b 2020-10-21 01:33:25  False
11  b 2020-10-21 01:34:12  False
12  b 2020-10-21 01:40:00   True
13  b 2020-10-21 01:41:48  False
14  b 2020-10-21 01:42:15  False
```

I want the final groups to be:

```
   id          event_time  delta
0   a 2020-10-21 01:00:34  False
1   a 2020-10-21 01:03:13  False
2   a 2020-10-21 01:05:13  False
--------------------------------     id : a
3   a 2020-10-21 01:11:25   True
4   a 2020-10-21 01:12:25  False
5   a 2020-10-21 01:13:25  False
--------------------------------

6   b 2020-10-21 01:21:25  False
--------------------------------
7   b 2020-10-21 01:30:25   True
8   b 2020-10-21 01:31:25  False
9   b 2020-10-21 01:32:20  False
10  b 2020-10-21 01:33:25  False     id : b
11  b 2020-10-21 01:34:12  False
--------------------------------
12  b 2020-10-21 01:40:00   True
13  b 2020-10-21 01:41:48  False
14  b 2020-10-21 01:42:15  False
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cumsum()` on the `delta` to identify the blocks, then groupby:

```
for k,d in df.groupby(['id', df['delta'].cumsum()]):
    print('-'*30)
    print(d)
```

**Note**: the above assumes that `df` is sorted by `id`. If this is not the case, then you need to group `delta` by `id` before cumsum:

```
for k,d in df.groupby(['id', df.groupby('id')['delta'].cumsum()]):
```

Output:

```
------------------------------
  id           event_time  delta
0  a  2020-10-21 01:00:34  False
1  a  2020-10-21 01:03:13  False
2  a  2020-10-21 01:05:13  False
------------------------------
  id           event_time  delta
3  a  2020-10-21 01:11:25   True
4  a  2020-10-21 01:12:25  False
5  a  2020-10-21 01:13:25  False
------------------------------
  id           event_time  delta
6  b  2020-10-21 01:21:25  False
------------------------------
   id           event_time  delta
7   b  2020-10-21 01:30:25   True
8   b  2020-10-21 01:31:25  False
9   b  2020-10-21 01:32:20  False
10  b  2020-10-21 01:33:25  False
11  b  2020-10-21 01:34:12  False
------------------------------
   id           event_time  delta
12  b  2020-10-21 01:40:00   True
13  b  2020-10-21 01:41:48  False
14  b  2020-10-21 01:42:15  False
```